# Array within database loop overwrites itself with keys from previous records

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a master query looping over records in a database that has to run a second query within the loop to pull all the images related to the record from another table. At the end of each loop I'm merging them together for one master json object that should output for each record.

It works perfectly on the first record. The problem is that when the master loop repeats over each record, the images array of the second query continues to add data from every previous record instead of just the current record.

In my database: 
Record 1 has 2 images associated. Record 2 has 1 image associated.

Problem with my code on JSON output:
Json Object 1 has 2 images. JSON object 2 is showing 2 images (it's carrying over an image from previous record - which I don't want it to do.)

```
 $query = "
 SELECT rooms.roomid, rooms.roomname 
 FROM rooms";
 $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
      $roominfo = $row;
      $roomid = $row['roomid'];

      query2 = "SELECT 
        roomimages.imageurl AS image,
        roomimages.imagetype AS imagetype
        FROM roomimages WHERE 
        roomimages.roomid = $roomid";
        $results2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);


        while($row2 = $results2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $type = $row2["imagetype"];
                    $imageurl = $row2["image"];
                    $rows2[$i] = [$type => $imageurl];
                    $i++;
                }
                $images = ["images" => $rows2];
                var_dump(json_encode($images));
         ..........

      $room[] = array_merge($roominfo, $images);
 }
```

For example when I dump each images array inside the loop:

Record 1:

```
  "{"images":[{"original":"https:...."}, 
    {"original":"test.jpg"}]}"
```

Record 2:

```
 "{"images":[{"original":"https:...."}, 
  {"original":"test.jpg"}]}"
```

BUT record 2 does not have test.jpg associated with it. It's getting pulled in somehow from the previous iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `$rows2` before you fetch results from query2. Note, I don't see a need for `$i` in your loop, you can just use `[]` shorthand notation for `array_push`:

```
$rows2 = array();
while($row2 = $results2->fetch_assoc()) {
     $type = $row2["imagetype"];
     $imageurl = $row2["image"];
     $rows2[] = [$type => $imageurl];
}
$images = ["images" => $rows2];
var_dump(json_encode($images));
```

Comment: @MojoAllmighty it's `$rows2` that needs resetting, not `$row2`... (unfortunate variable naming choice...)

Comment: OMG. thank you!!! simple and elegant. Why did I not even declare the array in the first place!